# Configure connection to embedded device with virtual COM port in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, com

I want to set up a connection between my Windows 7 computer and an embedded device connected on a virtual COM port using a USB cable. I already have a driver for for COM port emulation.

How do I configure the connection?

In windows XP, the answer is to go to:
`Create new connection` `->` `Advanced connection` `->` `Direct connection from PC to PC`

And then configure it. What's the corresponding approach for Windows 7? I've been searching through the "Network and Sharing Center" for ages without figuring it out, and I couldn't find much help in Google, either. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What configuration do you need? Baud rate, stop bits, that kind of stuff?

Comment: I meant setting it up, really, but I found the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

- Go to Network and Sharing Center
- Set up a new connection or network -> Set up a dial-up connection
- Enter a dummy number (not used) and choose 'Connect'.
- Edit the connection in order to configure (e.g. select COM port)
- Connect.